# How are prisoners in the CW's The Flash fed?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

The cells from the particle accelerator in the TV show "The Flash" don't look like they have a bathroom or a way to pass in food.
Is there an explanation in the comic books for this?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NobodyPoops

Comment: It's just your typical [P2C2E](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=P2C2E)!

Comment: Hard to say about the toilets, but the food would be easy enough to send it using an "airlock" system: open Door A, insert food, close Door A, open Door B, prisoner takes food and eats, prisoner returns tray, close Door B, open Door A, retrieve tray.  No sign of this in the show, so I'm not adding it as an answer, but it's an easy explanation.

Comment: @Nerrolken yeah food is easy, but toilets? baths? It's kind of inhumane to keep them locked inside such a tinny room

Comment: They're prisoners.  No reason to treat them well beyond necessities.

Comment: @BBlake exactly, but so far, they haven't even hinted that they're doing that bare minimum.

Comment: That question was actually asked by the moderator at the 2015 PaleyFest Flash Panel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=pSqs20ivrD8#t=266 - but as no answer was given it's not really worth turning it into one yet, but the producers state that it *will* be adressed in an upcoming episode.

Comment: Interesting, maybe we'll know more in future episodes, then :) Good catch!

Comment: Funny coincidence: The Atom asked the very same question in tonights episode of the Arrow (S03E19). He did not get an answer.

Comment: Kaitlyn goes down and flashes them on a regular basis. That's all the sustenance they require.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They order takeout.  How they get the food into the cells without letting the metahuman out isn't shown.  A deleted scene was recently released: (spoilers for S1E21, *Grodd Lives*)

It shows Caitlin wheeling a cart with a ton of takeout food on it.  She discusses some of the dietary preferences and restrictions of the imprisoned metahumans:

> I now know the dietary habits of all our metahuman inmates.  Did you know that the Weather Wizard orders Thai food every day?  And that Peekaboo loves enchiladas? And that Death Bolt is vegan?

So this is a regular thing that's been happening off-screen all season.

Comment: Updated, with a proper answer.

Comment: Video is now private.